# Select multiple using Rails `#select` form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-5, form-helpers

I've got a fairly simple (it seems) bit of code to create a multiple-selection element:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>  
  #stuff

  <%= fields_for :tags |tag_fields| %>
    <%= tag_fields.label :select_tags %>
    <%= tag_fields.select :tags, Tag.all, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason when it renders the page, the `multiple: true` part isn't getting parsed, and the form is just rendering as a generic dropdown with only one option selectable. What am I missing?

(Rails version is 5.0.0 in case relevant)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `multiple: true` in a hash like so: `{multiple: true}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) helper is:

```
select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

`multiple` is an HTML option, therefore you should use:

```
<%= tag_fields.select :tags, Tag.all, {}, multiple: true %>
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks! *Kicks self*. I'd gotten too comfortable with Ruby's generous hash arguments, and hadn't even registered that it could require two clearly separated hashes.